# How to update two SP list items using PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

We would like to connect 2 Sharepoint lists to one PowerApps gallery. So editing in in Form 1 with SP list 1, and then editing in Form 2 with SP list 2. The `Title` column in List 1 and List 2 are the same.

The gallery list is showing "Gallery.Selected" the filter is:

```
SortByColumns(
  Filter(
    [@BICT_DATA_KLANTEN_MAIN]; 
    StartsWith(
      Title; 
      ZOEKBALK_BICT_DATA_MAIN.Text
    )
  ); 
  "Title"; 
  If(
    SortDescending1; 
    Descending; 
    Ascending
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult for me to answer this question succinctly. There are SO many factors at play. To connect two Sharepoint lists to a single Gallery control, combine the lists into a single Collection.

**Example:**

```
ClearCollect(colCombined,
    SPList1,
    SPList2
)
```

- Add `colCombined` to the `Items` property of the Gallery.
- But this will add ALL records from both SP Lists.
- You *likely* don't want this because of unnecessary columns, size of data, etc.

Considering the Form controls you mentioned, put some thought into the relationships between List1 and List2. I'm imagining you want a `Header`-`Details`-type of relationship.

- Personally, I remove the `Title` column from Sharepoint lists then use a `recordGUID` column. Its more intuitive for me and others that come after me to maintain the app. "Title" says nothing about "ID key needed to relate lists".
- Research the PowerApps [GUID()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-guid) function. You'll want to populate the `recordGUID` column of both lists when creating new records.
- There is a 1-2hr class worth of nuance involved in creating a `Header/Details` type of application. From the UI to the Sharepoint best practices to the PowerFX code.

**Maybe useful for you...**
[image]